# Нужно получить текст внутри DIV'a без идентификатора

Tags: jquery

```
    <div class="wrapper-outer">
        <div class="wrapper-inner value-1">
            <div class="indoor">
                Значение 1.1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-inner value-2">
            <div class="indoor">
                Значение 2.1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-inner">
            <div class="indoor">
                Кнопка 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-outer">
        <div class="wrapper-inner value-1">
            <div class="indoor">
                Значение 1.2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-inner value-2">
            <div class="indoor">
                Значение 2.2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-inner">
            <div class="indoor">
                Кнопка 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    Задача: 
    1. получить "Значение 1.1" при нажатии на "Кнопку 1"
    1. получить "Значение 2.1" при нажатии на "Кнопку 2"

    Я пытался сделать так:
    var value = $(this).parent('.wrapper-outer').find('.value-1').find('.indoor').text();
    alert(value); // пустое значение
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `parent` на `closest` и всё заработает, `parent` идет вверх только на 1 уровень, `closest` пока не найдет:

```
var value = $(this).closest('.wrapper-outer').find('.value-1 > .indoor').text();
```

Comment: `find('.value-1 > .indoor')`

Comment: @Igor да точно, проглядел что 2 find шли